# if whereField could not be found

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

In my application I'm using discount codes, and this is going to check to things:

- If the discount code exists
- If the discount code exists but is already used.

  ```
      db.collection("discountCode").whereField("discountID", isEqualTo: txtfield_discountCode.text!).getDocuments(completion: { (query, err) in
      if let err = err{
          print(err.localizedDescription)
      }
      else{
          for documents in query!.documents{
              let data = documents.data()

              let discountCode = data["discountID"] as? String
              let percent = data["percent"] as? String
              let category = data["category"] as? String
              let expiring = data["expiring"] as? String

              self.checkIfCodeExists(discountCode: discountCode, percent: percent, category: category, expiring: expiring)
          }
      }
  })
  ```

But the code will always run to the "else-statement" even if no documents where "discountID" is equal to "txtfield_discountCode.text"

Is there anyway I can check if no fields is found that's equal to the textfield?

I've tried to do like this:

- (In the beginning of else) -> `if query!.documents == nil{ print("Code could not be found")}`

But that does not work.

So is there anyway I can check if ".wherefield" did not found any documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an error, you are just getting empty list from the database. Also you should safely unwrap your optionals.

You need something like this:

```
    guard let validCode = txtfield_discountCode.text else {
        print("code not entered")
        return
    }

    db.collection("discountCode").whereField("discountID", isEqualTo: validCode).getDocuments(completion: { (query, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let validQuery = query, !validQuery.documents.isEmpty {
                for documents in validQuery.documents {
                    let data = documents.data()
                    let discountCode = data["discountID"] as? String
                    let percent = data["percent"] as? String
                    let category = data["category"] as? String
                    let expiring = data["expiring"] as? String

                    self.checkIfCodeExists(discountCode: discountCode, percent: percent, category: category, expiring: expiring)
                }
            } else {
                print("Document not found")
            }
        }
    }
```